# In scale adaptation which should be done first? CFA or Reliability Analysis

Tags: reliability, scales, confirmatory-factor, explanatory-models

I am adapting questionnaire cross-cultural. Questinonnaire has 11 item and two factor. I want to confirm the structure

1 item's corrected item total correlation is <.20. Should this item be deleted before cfa?

Comment: Without more detail this is going to be hard to answer. What is the scientific question which leads you to want to do a confirmatory factor analysis? What is the substantive relationship between your manifest variables?

Comment: I am adapting questionnaire cross-cultural. Questinonnaire has 11 item and two factor. I want to confirm the structure

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please edit your question to reflect your comment.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an existing hypothesised structure which you wish to test whether derived from theory or from previous work then the appropriate method to do that is CFA. There does not seem to be any pressing reason to do a preliminary item analysis as is you remove an item what you will be testing then in your CFA is not the hypothesised model but one derived from it in a data dependent way.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Item which ı mentioned also has low factor loading in CFA (0.1). Can item with low factor load be deleted in CFA?

Comment: What scientiic question would be answered by deleting it?

Comment: obtain significant factor structure